# What is that "reader.readystate===2" . Please let me know

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file

I want to know about the  `reader.readystate===2`
Why use the 2 after `===` and meanings

```
  reader.onload = () => {
    if (reader.readyState === 2) {
      setAvatarPreview(reader.result);
      setAvatar(reader.result);
    }
  };

  reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
} else {
  setUser({ ...user, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
}
```

I have used that but I don't understand the `reader.readystate===2`

Answer (score 1):

It checks to see if the [status](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readyState) of the loading of the file is "Done".

Other possible statuses are Empty and Loading. Check the linked documentation for an explanation and more details.

Comment: This is the correct answer, but I'd suggest to the questioner that they use 
`reader.readyState === FileReader.DONE` 
to make the code clearer